# JSON Response to PHP Array

Tags: php, json

I'm using The Echo Nest API to find similar artists. The response looks like:

```
{"response": {"status": {"version": "4.2", "code": 0, "message": "Success"}, "artists": [{"name": "Audio Adrenaline", "id": "ARGEZ5E1187FB56F38"}, {"name": "Tree63", "id": "ARWKO2O1187B9B5FA7"}]}}
```

How can I take the artists it results and put them into an array? So I can then echo them later like:

```
echo $artist[0];
```

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) with the second parameter set to `TRUE`.

```
$str = '...';
$json = json_decode($str, TRUE);
$artist = $json['response']['artists'];    
//$artist = json_decode($str, TRUE)['response']['artists']; as of PHP 5.4

print_r($artist);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Audio Adrenaline
            [id] => ARGEZ5E1187FB56F38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tree63
            [id] => ARWKO2O1187B9B5FA7
        )

)
```

[**Codepad!**](http://codepad.org/3Ts0pZlY)

Answer (score 2):

[**json_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is what you need

```
$artist = json_decode($json);
```

or as an associative array

```
$artist = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode`, found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Sample:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

**Output**:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```